How to resolve 'No such file or directory' error for startup.sh in Azure App Service deployment?
Issue:
I am trying to deploy my Flask/ FastAPI application that uses WebSockets to Azure App Service. The application runs fine locally, but when deploying to Azure, it fails to start with the error: chmod: cannot access '/home/site/wwwroot/startup.sh': No such file or directory.
Project Structure:
My project repository on GitHub is structured as follows:
/my-app
├── .github
│   └── workflows
│       └── azure.yml 
├── app.py  
├── requirements.txt
├── folder
├── folder
├── haarcascadeclassifier
└── startup.sh

startup.sh
apt-get update
apt-get install -y libgl1-mesa-glx libglib2.0-0

gunicorn -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker -b 0.0.0.0:8000 app:app


Azure Configuration:
App Service on Linux
Python 3.10
Startup Command:
chmod +x /home/site/wwwroot/startup.sh && /home/site/wwwroot/startup.sh 
Logs:
From the Azure activity log:
2024-06-26T16:25:28.3624037Z Site's appCommandLine: 'chmod +x /home/site/wwwroot/startup.sh && /home/site/wwwroot/startup.sh'
...
2024-06-26T16:25:29.2838467Z chmod: cannot access '/home/site/wwwroot/startup.sh': No such file or directory
2024-06-26T16:25:29.182.052Z ERROR - Container videoemotion_0_e6593d58 for site videoemotion has exited, failing site start
2024-06-26T16:25:29.064Z ERROR - Container videoemotion_0_e6593d58 didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8000, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.

What I've Tried:
Verified that startup.sh is in the root directory of the GitHub repository.
Ensured the script is committed and pushed to the repository.
Checked the Azure Deployment Center and Log Stream for any additional errors.
Questions:
Why is the startup.sh script not being found during deployment?
How can I ensure the script is correctly recognized and executed by Azure App Service?
Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated!

Does the contents of the folder my-app get copied or does the folder my-app get copied to /home/site/wwwroot/? I think the folder gets copied, in which case you'd need to update your startup command to /home/site/wwwroot/my-app/startup.sh

How, exactly, is the /home/site/wwwroot directory created within the container, and how, exactly, is the startup.sh file copied there?  Is this done as part of a github workflow?  Is it done by a Dockerfile or similar?  Or some other way?

@PGHE I can't find my-app folder in /site/wwwroot/

@Lokmane ZEREG could please share your git link.

The issue you're encountering indicates that Azure App Service is unable to find the startup.sh script during deployment. Here are a few steps you can  check to resolve this:
Change the startup .sh:
#!/bin/bash
apt-get update
apt-get install  -y  libgl1-mesa-glx  libglib2.0-0
pip install  -r  requirements.txt
uvicorn main:app  --host  0.0.0.0  --port  8000

Add Startup Command:
Add Startup Command in general setting of tag Configuration in Azure Web App.
uvicorn main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000

Refer  my git for same code which  I have used for WebSocket connection with fast api.
app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
async def get(request: Request):
    return HTMLResponse(open("templates/index.html").read())

@app.websocket("/ws")
async def websocket_endpoint(websocket: StarletteWebSocket):
    await websocket.accept()
    protocol = "wss" if request.url.scheme == "https" else "ws"
    while True:
        data = await websocket.receive_text()
        await websocket.send_text(f"Message text was: {data}")



If  ws/http end point  has configured ,  https allow setting should set to off.


Sample  folder structure of fast api in git :

Deployment Status in git:

Azure web app Output:

